# What is the problem of Gaussianmixture in the sklearn package in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using Gaussianmixture (GM) of sklearn in python to identify the members of a star cluster. GM adjusted with two components and others are default. As seen in figure, one star (with red dots) seen that is clearly not a cluster member, appears as a member. Red dots gathered in the middle graph are porbably my members. But the single red dot on upper-left of this should not be a member. Because it is not close enough to this middle group.

[My cluster image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXPxC.jpg)

My python code is

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.colors as mtcolor

style.use("seaborn-white")
clist = ["gray", "red"]
cmap = mtcolor.ListedColormap(clist)

eX = pd.read_csv("mysatrs.csv", usecols=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).values

col0m = (eX[:,0] >= -5) & (eX[:,0] <= 5)
col1m = (eX[:,1] >= -5) & (eX[:,1] <= 5)
col2m = (eX[:,2] > 0)

X = eX[col0m & col1m & col2m]

plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))

hcgmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=2)
gmmfit = hcgmm.fit(X)
gmmprd = gmmfit.predict(X)
hcprobs = gmmfit.predict_proba(X)
hcmns = hcgmm.means_

plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=gmmprd, s=3, cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

Should another adjustment be do for GM?

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: the fit you get changes every time you run it, try a few times and keep the best one (the lowest `hcgmm.bic()`).  your data seems to have three dimensions and I guess this other one is throwing things off (including a link or plotting it would help).

if someone wants a longer example, here's a MWE.  first we pull in packages and generate some data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

background = np.random.randn(50,2) * 5
cluster = np.random.randn(50,2)

plt.scatter(background[:,0], background[:,1])
plt.scatter(cluster[:,0], cluster[:,1])
```

this gives something similar to the OP:

[image: random draw]

I can then fit a [GMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Gaussian_mixture_model) as the OP does by doing:

```
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=2)
fit = gmm.fit(X)
```

and plot the results with:

```
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=fit.predict(X))
```

but mostly I get terrible fits.  But after running a few times, I get this:

[image: fit with bic 993.5]

which shows we can (at least sometimes) recover a reasonable partition.  The [BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) of this fit was 993.5 while I often get values of >1000 that visually look terrible.

if I run `fit` 1000 times with the above random data I can generate a [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) that looks like:

[image: flipped CDF]

(x/y axes are the wrong way around, x is probability and y is BIC value) which says that it'll recover a good partition about 10% of the time.  Trying with other random draws says this varies, but I've not got better than ~40% success rate.

Given that you've only got a few points and components, you could try a much more computationally heavy approach.  I'd expect that a Bayesian MCMC mixture model would do much better here.

I've just remembered that the [Rand index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) is an easy way to check the accuracy of the partitions.  We can generate lots of test data, fit it and get the BIC and Rand index by doing:

```
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score

true_labels = (np.random.random(100) < 0.5).astype(int)
ix_a, = np.nonzero(true_labels == 0)
ix_b, = np.nonzero(true_labels == 1)

gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=2)

def test():
    X = np.empty((len(true_labels), 2), float)
    X[ix_a,:] = np.random.randn(len(ix_a), 2) * 5
    X[ix_b,:] = np.random.randn(len(ix_b), 2)

    fit = gmm.fit(X)
    ari = adjusted_rand_score(true_labels, fit.predict(X))
    return fit.bic(X), ari

fits = np.array([test() for _ in range(1000)])
```

and then plot the resulting distribution:

[image: plot of fits from above]

which shows we get nothing useful 76% of the time.  If we have 1000 data points (i.e. `X` has 1000 rows) then it recovers a reasonable partition most of the time.  However if I draw the `background` from a "Uniform(-10, 10)" distribution, e.g. with:

```
background = np.random.rand(500,2) * 20 - 10
cluster = np.random.randn(500,2)
```

it again fails horribly (ARI<0.5 ~ 99.5%).  Basically the GM model seems to deal very badly with non-Gaussian data.

Comment: Thanks Sam and sorry for missing data, [this my data](http://astronomi.istanbul.edu.tr/down/mystar.csv). I am not expert on python, but I will test your suggestion.

Comment: I am very sorry for filename conflict. File name is corrected, now above link active. Dear Sam, as much as I understand, your python knowledge is better than me, I will be very pleased, if you check my data with your code.